# Pre-processing txt document into a hashmap with String as key, and Integer ArrayList as value

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

For an assignment, I was asked to pre-process a txt document into a hashmap in order to have an efficient word search function. "To enable efficient word search, your code preprocesses the document, and stores all the words found in the document and the lines where they are found in a hash table (the words are the keys and the lines are the values)." I cannot figure out for the life of me, why I'm unable to replace the old value from a key, with a new value for the key. Here is the constructor that pre-processes the document.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();

public wordSearch() {
    char charChecker;
    String word;
    ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://homes.soic.indiana.edu/classes/spring2016/csci/c343-yye/docu.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while(in.hasNext()) {
            String str = in.nextLine();
            for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                for(int j = i+1; j < str.length(); j++) {
                    charChecker = str.charAt(j);
                    //check for word 
                    if(charChecker == ' ' ||
                       charChecker == ',' || 
                       charChecker == '.' ||
                       charChecker == '\n') {
                            word = str.substring(i, j);
                            //if word is already in HashMap
                            if(this.map.containsKey(word)) {
                                count = this.map.get(word);
                                count.add(lineNumber);
                                //System.out.println("[" + word + ", " + count.toString() + "]");
                                this.map.put(word, count);
                            }
                            //otherwise add word to HashMap
                            else {
                                count.add(lineNumber);
                                System.out.println(count.toString());
                                this.map.put(word, count);
                                //System.out.println("[" + word + ", " + count.toString() + "]");
                            }
                            i = j+1;
                            count.clear();
                    }
                }
            }
            lineNumber+=1;
        }
    in.close();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(this.map.toString());
}
```

Any advice on where to go from here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `count.clear();` use `count = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Existing code has same instance of count for all keys

Comment: Wow, that was so easy. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to check, if line numbers for a word exists.

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> lineNumbers;

if(...){
    word = str.substring(i, j);
    if ((lineNumbers = wordMap.get(word)) != null){
        lineNumbers.add(lineNumber);
    }else {
        lineNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        lineNumbers.add(lineNumber);
        wordMap.put(word, lineNumbers);
    }
    i = j+1
}
```